# How to rebase after a merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

We have a sequence of events like this:

1. Create branch A, and add a few commits to it
2. Time passes, hundreds of commits added to master
3. Master is merged into A
4. Time passes, maybe another 50 commits added to master

Is it possible to turn the merge in step 3 into a rebase? If nothing else, it would make the impending merge simpler as there would be less history to look at.

We haven't had rerere enabled.

Comment: That's definitely possible, did you try?

Comment: Heh, let me rephrase: how do you do this?

Comment: as per http://schacon.github.com/git/git-rebase.html - you're on branch A and run `git rebase master` (instead of `git merge master`)

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248231/git-rebase-after-previous-git-merge.

Answer (score 22):

Consider the following Git graph:

```
A...C...D...F
^       ^   ^ master
 \       \
  G...H...I...J
              ^ feature
```

The ... means "lots of commits".

Suppose we want to essentially rebase, i.e. take the commits in feature's history but not in master's history and reform them as a linear sequence of commits in master. This confounded by the fact that we merged master into feature at commit `I`. If we try to rebase, Git screws up because it tries to apply e.g. `C` on top of master and finds conflicts.

---

The best method is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141512/2665591), copied below for convenience:

```
git checkout feature
git branch -m feature-old
git checkout main
git checkout -b feature
git merge --squash feature-old
git commit
```

---

We can solve this problem by grabbing the actual changes from `feature` and packing them into a new commit.
Here's a way to do this using only very basic Git commands:

```
(1) git checkout feature
(2) git merge master
(3) git reset A
(4) git add -A  # This stages all working copy changes
(5) git commit -m "Every change between A and J"
```

In step (2), the `feature` branch has all changes in both `master` and `J`.
After step (3), HEAD points at `A`, but our working copy has all the changes from `master` and `J`, and steps (4) and (5) stage and commit those changes.

At this point our graph looks like this

```
A...C...D...F
^           ^ master
 \
  J'
  ^ feature
```

Note that `J'` contains everything in `A...F`. Now we do

```
git rebase master
```

Git happily applies the changes in `J'` as a new commit `J''`, but the only changes to add are those in `G...J` because the other changes are already in master. So now we have

```
  A...F<--J''
master^   ^feature
```

with all of the changes in our `feature` branch squashed into commit `J''`.
At this point, you can reset to `F` and re-apply changes in `J''` in a more granular fashion (even using `git add --patch`) if you want.

---

Another way to do essentially the same thing is with `read-tree` as explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258664/2665591)

```
git checkout master
git read-tree -u -m feature
```

---

Yet another way to do the same thing, stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43687128/2665591), is

```
git diff master > feature.patch
git checkout master
patch -p1 < feature.patch
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to find commit A ? Because that's what's blocking me right now

Comment: you are a rockstar!

Comment: The original solution didn't work for me, but the `read-tree` method did.

Comment: SIR YOU DID MAGIC! Solved so many of my issues. ^^. I would add to your solution, if you have a push or pull issues. Think of deleting remote and pushing branch back up. in my case 1 binary file from A on remote, was in conflict with J'' local when i tried to push. The one in J was actually a better matlab simulink file i did separately and saved under same name, hence no fast forward possible but actually not needed too. They told me to do a choose theirs or mine. it was mine obviously. but it gave me A merge link between A remote and J'' for my feature branch.

Comment: Using the first method, you would essentially be squashing the `feature` branch onto `master`, right? You would lose all the individual commits.

Comment: @somethingRandom yes, and you could reform things into individual commits using e.g. `git add --patch`.