# Git squash commits with merged branch

Tags: git, branch, squash

I am working on `master` branch, and had created a `fix` branch which merged back to master after job done:

```
  C ---.      | fix
 /      \
A -- B -- D   | master
```

By git log I can see:

```
commit 1992d90ff860b7f965d1cf24a199e2575f7761a9
Merge: 3ef8294 d2d8796
Date:   Fri May 30 13:07:02 2014 +0800

    Merge branch 'fix' -- D

commit d2d8796bc12a85b9948eee8d63fcbbf3b89d4aeb
Date:   Thu May 29 10:57:13 2014 +0800

    C

commit 3ef8294ce739f5f7524084b0b604132e40cf5fd9
Date:   Fri May 16 14:35:11 2014 +0800

    B

commit bfc45852466de4c3dcedc0ea24d8506312004e40
Date:   Fri May 16 10:31:39 2014 +0800

    A
```

Now I would like to squash commits of C,D into one commit:

```
A -- B -- E    | master
```

Usually I squash commits by rebase:

```
git rebase -i commit_of_B
```

But it is not working in this case, git complains:

```
error: could not apply d2d8796... C
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043961/git-squash-history-after-merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just found a way by `cherry-pick` with option `-m`:

```
git checkout -b work
git reset --hard HEAD^
git cherry-pick -m 1 1992d90ff
```

Now the branch is like:

```
A -- B -- D    | master
```